# Calculate Locations not adding Status field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

When I run the Calculate Locations tool, it inconsistently adds the `Status` field.  It consistently adds the `SourceID`, `SourceOID`, `PosAlong`, `SideofEdge`, `SnapX`, `SnapY`, and `Distance` fields.

I've tried the tool from both Toolbox and Model Builder, and both tools will apply the field to the same point feature class input (e.g. fire stations), but neither will apply it to another feature class input (e.g. addresses).

Cross-posted for visibility at [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/message/807516-calculate-locations-tool-not-adding-status-field)

Answer (score 1):

With help from GeoNet, the correct answer is that the Calculate Locations tool doesn't add a Status field to any result.  The info apparently came from a prior GP tool that saved results to the original data.

A workaround is to filter on SourceOID, where -1 indicates the point is not located.